# Algorithm to determine vista/windows 7 OS edition from product key

Tags: c++, algorithm, windows-7, windows-vista, product-key

We have to automatically create the XML file for an unattended vista/windows 7 installation in which we do write the product key (MAK type). Unfortunately the windows image contains multiple editions (home, home premium, professional, ultimate) so we need to decide which version we should use and write that info to the XML as well. And we would love beeing able to decide dynamically which edition to use.

Is there any public algorithm/way to determine the OS edition from the product key like windows setup does? Preferrably in C/C++.

**EDIT:** 
The question is not to determine which editions a certain images supports - this can be done simply by looking at the catalog files `sources\install_*.clg`

**EDIT2:**
I found some (strange) tools like Microsoft PIDX Check and Windows 7 Product Key Checker. These use the same `pidgenx.dll`. pkeyconfig.xrm-msof as the windows system itself. It can be used to determine, among others:

- The edition of the Windows.
- The features to unlock and activate.
- The distribution channel of the license.
- The license type.
- Ways to activate the operating system.
- Unique identifier to determine if activation should be accepted.

But the evaluation of a key takes awfully long.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Is it to display it in an about box or similar, or to determine if a certain feature is available?

Comment: I don't want to determine certain features - but the OS edition. I do need to set it in the unattended file or the installation will fail ("incorrect key") or at least ask to select the edition manually.

Answer (score 0):

They probably don't want anyone to know the format to make it harder for the keygen writers.

Some ISO's have a [ei.cfg](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744535(WS.10).aspx) file, you could check there

Comment: You are probably right. At least there is no documentation so far...
The ei.cfg does not help much. It only contains the maximum edition an image supports.